# Jquery button default state

Tags: jquery, html

i have problem with default state. Default state i get from database. Where i can put default state or how i should do?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.switch').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
    });
 });
```

`<button type="button" class="switch"><span><b>Off</b><b>On</b></span></button>`

app.js:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('mygbusena');
    var nusta = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
    });
    var smt = "SELECT busena FROM mygt where laikas=(select max(laikas) from mygt)";
    db.each(smt, function(err, row) {
    console.log(row.busena);
    nusta = row.busena;
    })
           setInterval(function(){
           socket.emit('mygnustatyta', nusta);
       console.log(nusta);
      }, 1000);
});
```

index.html:

```
    var socket = io.connect('http://myip:3000');
    var nust = document.getElementById('mygnustatyta');
    socket.on('mygnustatyta',function(data){
        console.log('Connected');
        mygnustatyta.innerHTML = data
```

Comment: what do you mean with "default state"?

Comment: Then refresh page i get only off now, i want change this value

Comment: could you add code about reading default state from database?

Comment: have a look here http://olance.github.io/jQuery-switchButton/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add bold effect in your .css file:

```
.switch span{font-weight:bold;}
```

and in .js file

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
       $('.switch').click(function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('on');
          var text = $(this).hasClass('on')?'On':'Off';
          $(this).children('span').text(text);
       });
    });
```

where you HTML is:

```
 <button type="button" class="switch"><span>Off</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your button an ID and change your click event selector to the given ID. Your button click event is currently associated with a class.  We the button class changes the button event will not fire.

```
$('#button').click(function()  {
    var class='switch';
    if($(this).class() == 'switch') { 
        class=' on';
    }
    $(this).toggleClass(class);
});
```